# Cannot access object: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'hello' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to loop over an array in angular2, but I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object 'hello' of type 'string'. NgFor
>   only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

This only happens as soon as I access the array from the component.

My code in the component looks like this:

```
export class StringTestComponent implements OnInit {
  strings: string[];
  currentString: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.strings = ['hello', 'hey'];
    this.changeCurrentString(0);
  }

  changeCurrentString(id: number): void {
    this.currentString = this.strings[id];
  }
}
```

And the error occurs with the following html (I changed the names of objects for this example):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div *ngFor="let string of strings; let i=index" 
       (click)="changeCurrentString(i)" 
       [ngClass]="strings[i] === currentString ? 'active' : ''">
     {{string}}
  </div>
</div>
```

As long as I do not call `changeCurrentString`, all goes well. So it has to do with accessing the object I'd assume?

Hope anybody can help!

Comment: Except for the echonax's remark, and for the fact that you don't need an index (just use `(click)="currentString = string"` and `string === currentString`), your code doesn't show the problem you describe: http://plnkr.co/edit/P2jXki0Q68pVnOrMUemV?p=preview. So your real code must be different from what you posted. Your real code tries iterating with ngFor on a string ('hello') rather than an array

Comment: don't use string as variable name its a keyword in typescript representing TYPE string

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for your comment, and indeed I did change something else. I'm not quite sure what the exact mistake in the code was however, but it probably was some kind of typo. 

In means of the function, I need to do other stuff than `currentString = string`, but normally yes, that would be a better solution. 

@Sreemat maybe a bad choice of wording, but it was purely meant as example. Place any other variable name in place and it illustrates the same.